# Fixing up beat up wide plank floors

Tags: wood, floor, woodworking, hardwood-floor, old-house

My farmhouse is about 120 years old. There is a lot of carpet upstairs, which I would love to remove. I have pets and allergies and I just think carpets are gross.

I can understand why someone decided to put in carpet. The boards underneath are worn wide plank boards, but I don't think they are bad enough to justify a total replacement. There are some small cracks, gaps at the edges, and chipped corners. Nothing I see so far is big enough to warrant cutting wood strips to fill it in.

The previous owners ripped all of the carpet out of the master bedroom, filled the cracks, and painted over everything. This has held up very well, and the filler shows no signs of wear for years now. I want to take this approach with the rest of the upstairs that is still carpeted.

My question is what kind of product I should use to fix the cracks. I don't know what they used or if painting helped reinforce it. I do like the natural wood look, but that's not an option for these boards. They have already been painted brown.

I have some architectural salvage stores available in my region, so if I run into any bigger gaps during the process I will replace larger holes or missing boards with reclaimed wood if I need to. I think I understand everything that needs to be done to get what I want, I'm just not familiar with filler and putty.

I would like to preserve the character of the floors, so this seems like the best way to do that. I am not interested in having a new clean look to my floors or restoring them to look younger, I just want to level out the damaged areas and paint everything over.

During my research so far, it seems that many of the tutorials and diy info is about people who are re-staining their floors, so since I am planning on painting them after repair, I am wondering how this would change the process or products I should use.

Comment: You have more choice if painting over than with staining/clear coats, since you do not need any matching of colour, just want a flat surface.  Wood filler or just wood glue mixed with sawdust should work.  If not testing the paint for lead, should not sand without a good mask and cleanup system.

Comment: What kind of flooring is underneath the carpets? By "cracked" do you mean the wood boards have separated rather than the wood itself is split? Do you have a subfloor? Are the boards surface nailed? Tongue-in-groove? Hardwood floor "patches" are notoriously bad because they're never strong enough to flex with the natural movement of the floor.

Comment: Not a lot of homes in Fla. with wood floors, but a friend does have one with the same issues as you have.  He filled the splits and cracks and some minor termite damage with auto body filler.  It can be sanded smooth easily and takes paint well.  Did this about 7 years ago and the floors still look great.